# DotNetOpenAuth and Refresh Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I have an existing custom OAuth 2.0 process within my current MVC 4 environment that handles one provider's OAuth services.  In my process I'm storing Access Tokens and Refresh Tokens and recalling them, server-side for access to services (ditto for refreshing the access token with the refresh token, as needed).

I'm looking to standardize and add more services to my site, so naturally I've turned to DotNetOpenAuth.  I will preface this with saying that I have only been *reading* the documentation so far.  My big question is this: knowing that I already have a data source for storing and retrieving refresh tokens, can this be incorporated into my implementation of DotNetOpenAuth?

I guess I'm generally confused with how DotNetOpenAuth manages the access token and the refresh token, as the examples I'm reading make it feel like it's automagically managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth does not store access or refresh tokens, but relies on the app to do that. Since you already do, adding DotNetOpenAuth should be fairly easy. You may need to implement a fairly simple `IAuthorizationState` interface when you pass your refresh token into DotNetOpenAuth, but that would be all.